# How to move windows between displays in KDE-KWin

Tags: kde

So I'm using [kde](/questions/tagged/kde) and I have two monitors: HDMI2 (primary), VGA1, configured as as extended desktop.

I'm looking for a way to move windows between displays be means of a keyboard shortcut (akin to using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> in MS-Windows).

[compiz](/questions/tagged/compiz) seems to have the Put extension just for this reason.

Is there anything for KDE that could do this? I'm using KDE 4.9.5